# Re-casting types of all column in SparkR data frame in a loop and/or apply function

Tags: r, apache-spark, casting, type-conversion, sparkr

With [**SparkR 1.4.1**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/R/index.html) when working with a data frame of structure:

```
printSchema(dta)
root
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- valA: float (nullable = true)
 |-- valB: float (nullable = true)
 |-- ...
```

I would like to convert ***all*** of the existing columns to strings, **without explicitly referring to each column by name.**

## Desired approach

Desired approach would loop over all columns:

```
# Quickly creating new data frame
dtaTmp <- select(dta, "date")

# Looping through each column of old data frame and adding string equivalent
# to a newly created data frame
for (i in seq_along(columns(dtaTmp))) {
    print(i)
    x  <- cast(eval(parse(text = paste(sep = "$", "dtaTmp", columns(dtaTmp)[i]))), 
           "string")
    dtaTmp <- withColumn(dtaTmp, (columns(dtaTmp)[i], x)
}
```

This fails with error: **`returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE`**. In effect I'm looking for a solution that would enable me to run equivalent of `sapply(mtcars, as.character)` on SparkR data frame.

### Desired results

a new data frame should be of structure:

```
printSchema(desiredDta)
root
 |-- date: string(nullable = true)
 |-- valA: string(nullable = true)
 |-- valB: string(nullable = true)
 |-- ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting a bug in 1.4 branch where `withColumn` retains duplicated column names. The simplest solution is to use a single `select` with a list of columns:

```
select(df, lapply(columns(df), function(x) alias(cast(df[[x]], "string"), x)))
```